# Spellchecker path not active

Tags: lyx

I have upgraded lyx 2.0.2 to 2.1.4, now dictionary is not working.
Path of Hunspell dictionaries is not active. Tool>Preferences>Path>Hunspell dictionaries is disabled.

Comment: I am having exactly this same issue. I'm not able to enter a path in the text entry box. Did you find a solution? The answers below don't seem to apply.

Answer (score 0):

Spell did not work for me either.

I was able to make it work by downloading `en_US.dic` and `en_US.aff` from [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/lyxwininstaller/files/hunspell/) and using these to overwrite those in the Lyx 2.1.4 installation subfolder `~\Resources\dicts` and restarting LyX.

See section 6.14 Spell Checking in the [LyX User's Guide](http://wiki.lyx.org/LyX/Manuals).

Answer (score 0):

Why do they give answers for windows on a site dedicated to ubuntu?
Okay. I have 20 ubuntu.
Here's what helped:

```
sudo apt-get install -y hunspell-xx
```

where xx is the language.